# Applying preprocess on a TensorFlow Dataset takes long time

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to apply a preprocessor to remove html tags from the fileds of a Tensorflow dataset. I use this in the implementation of `t5` which uses `segio`.

in `my_preprocessor` if I use `text = row[field_index]`, it works okay and in training, it prints several rows and continues, but if I use `text = normalize_text(row[field_index])` it hangs on an infinite or long loop as if it wants to apply it on the whole dataset rows!

```
def normalize_text(text):
    """Lowercase and remove quotes and tags from a TensorFlow string."""
    text = tf.strings.lower(text)
    text = tf.strings.regex_replace(text,"'(.*)'", r"\1")
    text = tf.strings.regex_replace(text,"<[^>]+>", " ")
    return text

def make_add_field_names_preprocessor(
    field_names: Sequence[str], field_indices: Optional[Sequence[int]] = None,
) -> Callable:

   def my_preprocessor(ds):
        def to_inputs_and_targets(*row):
            ret = {}
            count=0
            tf.print("=======================")
            for field_name, field_index in zip(field_names, field_indices):
                # if I use this, it works okay
                text = row[field_index]
                # if I use the following it falls to a long or endless loop
                text = normalize_text(row[field_index])
                tf.print(count, "Row:",text)
                ret[field_name] = text
                count+=1
            return ret
        return ds.map(to_inputs_and_targets,
                    num_parallel_calls=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    return my_preprocessor
```

**Update**: The preprocessor gets two field names, "inputs" for row[1], and "targets" for row[2]. I noticed that the problem exists many when I call `normalize_text` on `row[2]`

Comment: How about trying BeautifulSoup to remove the html tags instead?

Comment: @yudhiesh my problem is the logic of this code, it seems if I apply any function of a row it doesn't work

Comment: I can use `tf.strings.regex_replace(text,"<[^>]+>", " ")` instead of calling normalize_text, but the problem is the same. It prints the text without HTML tags, but the problem is that the training or even looping over some examples takes too long time.

Comment: Hmm perhaps instead of using `tf.string` methods which work on tensors of strings, try using the builtin methods, like `text.lower()` and using `re.sub()`.

Comment: @yudhiesh I'm trying but initially it says `'Tensor' object has no attribute 'replace'`